# Jquery Remove Div and Alert is not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a following code, i want to remove label and Input Box on click, but it is not working
no any alert is shown, nothing is seen over the console.. really disappointed

```
<div id="Div1" class="span5 well droppedFields ui-droppable ui-sortable">
    <div class="draggableField ui-draggable droppedField" style="z-index: 10;" id="CTRL-DIV-1002">
        <div style="z-index: 11;"><span id="LabelU2">LastName : </span></div>
        <div style="z-index: 12;">
            <input name="LastName" type="text" id="LastName"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my jquery

```
 $('.draggableField ui-draggable droppedField').on('click', function () {
            $(this).parent('div.DivHTML').remove();
            alert("hi");
        });
```

Help is apperciable. thnx

Comment: You have an error in your selector .. all the classes should be prefixed with point (.) like this :  $('.draggableField .ui-draggable .droppedField') Which means that droppedField is inside ui-draggable which is inside the draggableField.

Comment: `$('.draggableField.ui-draggable.droppedField')` Good idea to review your basic CSS selector syntax.

Comment: It's protocol for *you* to create a fiddle with your code first.

Comment: There is no element with class `DivHTML`. How can jQuery remove a non-existent element?

Comment: If it isn't working in your project but is on the fiddle then there is something else in your code causing the issue.  You don't have everything in your fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector doesn't point to anything.  There is no `draggableField` that has a child `ui-draggable` that has a child `droppedField`. Do you mean a div that has all three classes?

```
$('.draggableField.ui-draggable.droppedField').on('click', function () {
  $(this).hide();
  alert("hi");
});
```

UPDATED CODE: Removed the OP code to `remove()` element and replaced with `hide()`

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does it mean "the correct element was selected but the event code didnt work".  Or does it "the selector did not select the correct element".  Please provide details if you want help.

Comment: Please look at my JSFIDLE in my question, remove only one label&text box first time, another textboxs are removed but there llabels are not removed

Comment: actually .remove is used, coz i am saving the innerHTML of the form, any Great answer, i apperciate

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrp04w76/)

```
$('.draggableField').on('click', function() {
        $(this).find("input").remove();
        $(this).find("#LabelU2").html('');
    });
```

Comment: Review fiddler page I don't see any change

Answer (score 0):

you don't have `DivHTML` in there:

use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.draggableField.ui-draggable.droppedField').on('click', function () {
  $(this).parent('div').remove();
  alert("hi");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we see more details on your project? If it's working in jsfiddle but not in your project it seems like something else is missing. Are you loading jquery or your specific script into your html page properly? To get down to the problem we need more to go off of.